# How do get github author's handle from git log?

Tags: github

I can easily get a git author's name and email from the log by doing this:

```
git --no-pager show -s --format='%aN <%ae>'
```

Which shows `Some User <someusers@email.com>`

---

How do I get the github handle?  For instance, how to get `@someuser`?

Do I really need to make a request to Github's API or is there a better way?

Comment: Who says they have a github account just because they use git?

Comment: Good point.  Reframing question to just github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While git doesn't "map/link/reference" github usernames, you can use a browser and do a lookup on github by e-mail address. Mainly for e-mail addresses which are primary addresses, though. For example, if you wanted to try to find "mark@mark-story.com", then you can send that as a query in the URL string for the "Users" search.

https://github.com/search?q=mark%40mark-story.com&ref=simplesearch&type=Users&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Subsequently, you can just use that page's search box to find other users by e-mail address.

How to get there from the main page:

- https://github.com/
- Search for "mark@mark-story.com"
- Click "Users" in the left-column's results filters

**NOTE:** A github user may use many secondary addresses and those aren't in the above search system.

After nailing down the search/lookup, you could get creative and make some kind of substitution for `git log` by producing a cache to map them n-to-n.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can get that information just from git.. you need to use the GitHub API